# A way to hand off a Rail connection to delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

We have an existing API where a client asks our server for information that we have to get from another external server.  When the external server takes a long time, say 10 seconds, it holds up a Rails passenger instance for that whole 10 seconds.

Is there some way to pass the rendering of our reply to delayed_job so that I can free up the Rails instance?

NOTE: Ideally, we would just update our API and reply to our API client that we are busy and to try back again in a few seconds to see if we are ready.  However, there are already thousands of clients out there and changing them is not practical at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to handle this is to queue up the job and return immediately, then poll or use some async notification framework like Pusher or Faye to update the remote client.  You definitely cannot pass the connection to DJ as you describe.  Another avenue you might investigate is using EventMachine to handle it, a lá http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2011/05/04/eventmachine-and-passenger/.  A third alternative would be to precache the data from the remote web service, but that is an avenue very dependent on what you're doing (authorization, for example, is not something you could do there.)

The basic bottom-line is that you're dealing with a bit of an architecture issue. If you absolutely have to talk to the remote service AND output the results in the request cycle, there's not a lot you can do about it short of changing to a more evented backend like EventMachine or Node.js.

Comment: By the way, the technical reason you can't do what you're asking is that your DJ worker runs in another process (else it would block your request, which is what you're dealing with now), and you can't share connections across the process boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Just curious. Who says you "can't share connections across process boundary"? Linux? NGINX? Passenger? Rack? Other?

Comment: I guess i'd say its an OS level thing.  For most OS's the process encompasses all the memory it has access to. It might be interesting to see what could be done with shared memory spaces, but I'm not enough of a OS-level geek to know, TBH.